# Django: ForeignKey dependency vs. call dependency

Tags: django, one-to-many

I have two apps, e.g. cars and exhibitions. Cars manages Car objects, exhibitions manages car exhibitions. Since an Exhibition consist of many cars, I need a one-to-many relationship from Exhibition to Car. Usually I would model this as a ForeignKey from Car to Exhibition.

On the other hand, exhibitions do things with cars, so Exhibition objects need to access Car objects and call methods on them. Therefore I have to import cars.models into exhibitions.models.

So I have a call dependency of exhibitions on cars and a ForeignKey dependency of cars on exhibitions. Therefore the cars app is installed before the exhibitions app and cannot create the ForeignKey relationship to Exhibition, because that model does not yet exist.

I am wondering what is the best solution to this problem. I do not want to regroup my apps though.

The one solution I came up with, is to implement the one-to-many relationship from Exhibition to Car by a ManyToManyField in Exhibition. I do not like that solution though, because it is more overhead (requires additional table and so on) and also makes it possible to assign one car to multiple exhibitions which I do not want.

So what is a better solution?

Comment: Opinion based questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. If there's a problem you're having with some code, please add the code to you question, otherwise it will most likely be closed by the community.

Comment: @Brandon: I see it as a design question. As with all design questions there are trade-offs that can be discussed. However being a design question it is hard to show code. Everybody knowing Django should understand the question without code.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. I may understand your question, but that doesn't negate the fact that S.O. has a vote to close option for questions that are primarily opinion based. This site is for *specific* questions related to code, for which there is a minimal amount of effort shown for research. It is probably a better fit for: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/. I'm not trying to be rude or anything. I'm just saying your question doesn't fit the format.